# FOSRestBundle listen on prefix only

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I have a Symfony application app and running, I want to run the FOSRestBundle on a prefix only /api/*
I did some research and found one answer that mentioned using zone

```
zone:
    - { path: ^/api/* }
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to find template "" (looked into......

This is my config:

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener: false
    zone:
        - { path: ^/api/* }
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true
```

And this is the controller:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;


class APIRestController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Rest\Get("api/gettime")
     */
    public function getTimeAction()
    {
        $restresult = new \DateTime();

        $view = View::create($restresult, 200);
        return $view;

    }
```

Also:

```
"friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "2.0.0",
"jms/serializer-bundle": "^2.0"
```

I spent hours reading the documentation and looking online but with no luck, I just keep going in circles!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your configuration:

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: [ 'json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: true }
    zone:
        - { path: ^/api/* }
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true
```